# Как показать плотность распределения величины на гистограмме, что-то похожее на density?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

Как показать плотность распределения величины на гистограмме, что-то похожее на `density` (сумма всех столбцов равна 1)?

```
density = counts / (sum(counts) * np.diff(bins)
```

, а мне бы вместо него только: `counts / sum(counts)` - количество элементов в диапазоне из массива arr на число элементов массива `arr`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
    
arr = [1, 2, 2, 22, 33, 43, 80]
plt.hist(arr, np.linspace(1, 100, 5), edgecolor = "black", color='blue', density=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы хотите отобразить плотность распределения, то это легко делается в Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(arr)
s.plot.kde()
```

PS площадь фигуры ограниченной графиком сверху и осью `X` снизу - стремится к единице.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не, мне нужна столбчатая диаграмма, где значение вероятности для диапазона = количество элементов в диапазоне из массива arr / число элементов массива arr. Все полученные столбики должны давать в сумме 1.

Comment: @pythmy, ну тогда посчитайте ручками то, что вам нужно и нарисуйте обычную столбчатую диаграмму `plt.bar()` и не используйте `plt.hist()`

Comment: там не совсем ясно как работать с диапазонами, вот в этом сложность

Comment: @pythmy, приведите в вопросе численный пример данных который вы хотите получить на основе `arr`

Comment: получилось) спасибо